# How to checkout remote branch as the new one without tracking in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I know how to easily achieve this via command line:
`git checkout -b <new branch> --no-track origin/master`

However, I see no option for `--no-track` in UI.

Is there any global setting for this?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. You can set the `branch.autoSetupMerge` configuration variable to `false` in global git configuration as a workaround.

Comment: If you don't need​ tracking, use New branch action (either from branches widget, or from the Log context menu). Also please follow the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-193354